# Ionic filter. Make ion-searchbar work.?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have tried so many times to make the ionic searchbar work. I've tried pipes, but I just don't understand how it works. On the ionic site I saw this document http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#searchbar and tried to implement this to my code but it did not work out. Deleted all the code and this is what I currently have.

#### HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color ="primary">

    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>{{ appName }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-md-3 col-lg-2  col-xs-6 *ngFor="let item of items">
          <ion-card class="kaart">
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img class="pic" [src]="item.avatar" />
          </ion-avatar>
           <h2>{{item.voornaam}}</h2>
           <h2>{{item.achternaam}}</h2>
           <p>{{item.groep}}</p>
           <ion-icon color ="primary" class="call" name="call"></ion-icon>
           <ion-icon color ="primary" class="chatboxes" name="chatboxes"></ion-icon>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

#### ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})

export class Page1 {
appName = 'Pezo';
items:any;

    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {

      this.items = [
      {voornaam: 'Mert', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 1'},
      {voornaam: 'Ask Sana', achternaam: 'Benzer', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 1'},
      {voornaam: 'Koray', achternaam: 'Avci', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 1'},
      {voornaam: 'Recep', achternaam: 'Ivedik', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 3'},
      {voornaam: 'Gel', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 2'},
      {voornaam: 'Yarim', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 3'},
      {voornaam: 'Gonlume', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 3'},
      {voornaam: 'Huzur', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 2'},
      {voornaam: 'Ver', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 2'},
      {voornaam: 'Omrume', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 2'},
      {voornaam: 'Soylesin', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 3'},
      {voornaam: 'Tum', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 3'},
      {voornaam: 'Sarkilar', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 2'},
      {voornaam: 'Mustafa', achternaam: 'Ceceli', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 2'},
      {voornaam: 'Real', achternaam: 'Madrid', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 4'},
      {voornaam: 'Is', achternaam: 'Kampioen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 4'},
      {voornaam: 'Ruud van', achternaam: 'Nistelrooy', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 4'},
      {voornaam: 'Dennis', achternaam: 'Bergkamp', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 4'},
      {voornaam: 'Emre', achternaam: 'Mor', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 4'},
      {voornaam: 'Irem', achternaam: 'Derici', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 4'},
      {voornaam: 'qwertyuioplk', achternaam: 'qwertyuioplk', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 2'},
      {voornaam: 'Cristiano', achternaam: 'Ronaldo', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 1'}
      ]
      this.items = this.items.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.voornaam < b.voornaam) ? -1 : (a.voornaam > b.voornaam) ? 1 : 0 ;});
}
}
```

Comment: Have you added `(ionInput)="someFunction($event)"` to the `<ion-searchbar>`, in your attempts?

Comment: Yes I've added to the searchbar yes

Comment: What property do you want to search by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a copy of you `items`-array, in my example `filteredItems`, that you can filter depending on input. On each input event 'refill' the `filteredItems` and filter it again it using the new input value.
Also use the `filteredItems`-array in your `*ngFor`-loop.

EDIT:
Added `item.achternaam &&` and `item.voornaam &&` as 'guards'. If the `item` does not have the property `voornaam` or `achternaam` then the execution inside that parenthesis will stop and evaluate to `false`.

**TS**

```
export class Page1 {
    items:Array<any>;
    // Add another array that will hold the objects that match the
    // search result
    filteredItems:Array<any>;

    constructor() {

        this.items = [
            {voornaam: 'Mert', achternaam: 'Sezen', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 1'},
            // ...and many more                
            {voornaam: 'Cristiano', achternaam: 'Ronaldo', avatar: 'http://placehold.it/100', groep: 'Groep 1'}
        ]
        this.items = this.items.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.voornaam < b.voornaam) ? -1 : (a.voornaam > b.voornaam) ? 1 : 0 ;});

        // Make this function call
        this.initFilteredItems();
    }

    // This function makes `this.filteredItems` hold a reference to the 
    // `this.items`-array.
    initFilteredItems(){
        this.filteredItems = this.items;
    }

    // Function that performs the filtering
    filterItems(ev:any){
        // In case the `this.filteredItems` has been used before e.g.
        // containing a subset of `this.items`, we need to make it hold
        // a reference to the `this.items` again, which contains the
        // whole set of objects.
        this.initFilteredItems();

        // Get the new input-value
        let val = ev.target.value;

        // Make sure it contains a value and remove trailing whitespaces
        if(val && val.trim() != ''){
            // the `Array.prototype.filter()` returns a new array with
            // all elements that pass the test implemented by the 
            // provided function
            this.filteredItems = this.filteredItems.filter(item => {
                // Here filter by `voornaam` and `achternaam`
                // We use 'guards' (item.voornaam and item.achternaam) in
                // the beginning of each parenthesis set to check if these
                // properties exist on `item`, if not it evaluates to false.
                // Then we call `toLowerCase()` on both the property and 
                // the input-value to make the search case-insensitive.
                // The `indexOf()`-function checks if the input-value exists
                // in the property and returns the index if it does and -1
                // if it doesn't.
                return (item.voornaam && item.voornaam.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1) || 
                   (item.achternaam && item.achternaam.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
<!-- Here we register that `filterItems()` should be called when the
     `ionInput`-event fires, and pass the event data. -->
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <!-- Here in the `*ngFor` we use the property in our component class
           that contains the search result (`filteredItems`) -->
      <ion-col col-md-3 col-lg-2  col-xs-6 *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">
          <ion-card class="kaart">
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img class="pic" [src]="item.avatar" />
          </ion-avatar>
           <h2>{{item.voornaam}}</h2>
           <h2>{{item.achternaam}}</h2>
           <p>{{item.groep}}</p>
           <ion-icon color ="primary" class="call" name="call"></ion-icon>
           <ion-icon color ="primary" class="chatboxes" name="chatboxes"></ion-icon>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Looks like you have to remove the } that the error-message is pointing at.

Comment: I dont see the ionic cards.  Any idea why?

Comment: Debug the filter-function to make sure it works properly.

Comment: It doesnt work with the filteredItems, when I change it it works but then I get another error

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: If I change filteredItems to items, I can see the ionic cards but get this error: https://gyazo.com/d116a6b73c64b94e64887522dafe1e0b . But I dont know why it doesnt work without the filteredItems. Because you have this : initFilteredItems(){
        this.filteredItems = this.items;
    }

Comment: Yeah sorry, i know now why you didnt see the cards, notice my latest edit, i added a function call to `this.initFilteredItems()` at the end of the constructor.

Comment: Ah nice, I see it now! But I get the same error with cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: Made a new edit, look at the `filterItems()`-function.

Comment: Thanks it worked, can you edit the answer and explain what you did. I would appreciate that.

Comment: Want more explanation?

Comment: Can you comment in the code. Thank you so much for the help and time!

Comment: btw in the code it is voornaam and not voornam. Just saying it, because someone can be confused about that.. : if(val && val.trim() != ''){
            this.filteredItems = this.filteredItems.filter(item => {
                return (item.voornam && item.voornam.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1) || 
                   (item.achternaam && item.achternaam.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            })
        }
    }
}

Comment: There! Got some more comments for you :) Be sure to upvote (the 'up-arrow') if you appreciate the answer! :)